# MapReduce performance. emit. Single vs Multiple?

Tags: mongodb, performance, optimization, mapreduce, bigdata

Let's say, we have a MongoDB collection with **a lot of** documents. I need to execute MapReduce on this collection. **out** value is **"inline"**. The value of **emit** is kinda big and can be separated on multiple almost similiar groups, e.g.:

```
{
teen_walk: 0, teen_car: 0, teen_bicycle: 0,
adult_walk: 0, adult_car: 0, adult_bicycle: 0, adult_plane: 0
}
```

There are more groups, I'm just out of imagination. The problem is: which way of collecting this data set is faster: the single big-emit-valued MapReduce or multiple smaller-emit-valued MapReduces?

Will two MR executions with conditions, given above and emit values:

```
{walk, car, bicycle}
```

and

```
{walk, car, bicycle, plane}
```

collect result faster?

**EDIT** Data is being collected by mongodb-java-driver inside BIRT report.

**EDIT 2** Generally speaking, the question is: "Which way will collect required data set faster: one MapReduce execution with monolithic emit value or multiple MapReduces with smaller emit values?". But possible similarities of those executions can be taken into account.

Comment: Have you tried both? Which was faster? It's hard to give a concrete answer without actual code.

Comment: @wdberkeley, no, I haven't. I don't have a mongodb with a huge number of documents right now. It will be used later, in production. Maybe there are some guidelines/examples/articles/online sandboxes to test/etc. about the topic?

Comment: There's not much context, but naively I'd say doing all the work in one m/r is fster, since you avoid double the overhead.

Comment: @wdberkeley and, generally, that is the question: which overhead is less/bigger. In memory and/or in CPU usage.

Comment: Since we lack a complete set of quantifiable data her to make any consideration on then it seems like you just made a major "boo boo" by wasting 300 of you rep score on an unqualified question that no-one can reasonably answer with any respectable authority at this point. Unless you can add something more reasonable to your question, then I only expect very "lame" answers that will not actually provide a solution, but may possibly earn some unworthy person the bounty points you just put on offer. You should have improved your question earlier.

Comment: why don't you just fill a DB with a lot of random data (that fits your needs) and see what is faster?, if you are working with mongodb without having a database or data (real or faked) your chances of success are small IMO

Comment: I think for a while I will leave this question as is. If starting bounty was a mistake, then at least others may not repeat it. If answer will be community-liked, I will accept it.

Comment: @UnknownJoe Why are you using Map/Reduce, as far as I now it isn't really a real time material, you should use [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0):

This simply depends on your hardware/architecture.
In general, the more CPUs you have working on your MRs, the smaller the values can be (this is kind of obvious: if you have 1000 CPUs but you only emit 10 values, then 990 CPUs will not do a thing).
However, if you emit too many values, your network throughput must keep up. If your network is fast enough (maybe you have a HPC-cluster or supercomputer), then MR is actually slower than traditional methods.
The reason why Google introduced MR is because they don't have something like a supercomputer, but plenty of distributed datacenters.
So here you have it: Test it on your system and you'll know :).